# Magento2.3:CSS inlining error: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in selector >> body <<

Tags: error, email, magento2.3.0

> CSS inlining error: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in selector >> body << in /home/rcg40548/public_html/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/Classes/Emogrifier.php on line 374

I also have used this solution but it is not working.

Solution:

```
create the files
/web/css/email.less
/web/css/email-inline.less
in your custom theme and add the content from
/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less and
/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-inline.css
respectively
but each with the line "@import 'source/_theme.less';" commented out (or removed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facing the same issue:
I was using the php7.3 (**Which is the main issue**).
Just downgrade the php version 7.3 to 7.2